# Interaction between Activity and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

On the press of a button, I initiate the uninstall of another application and need to know if uninstall of that app was success or not so that I can update my app's UI accordingly.

I have written a broadcast received for the same but in my activity how do I know if app was uninstalled.

My Button press code:

```
if(planet.isChecked()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+planet.getPackageInfo().packageName));
                        startActivity(intent);
}
```

My broadcast receiver:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, " onReceive !!!! PACKAGE_REMOVED",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: If you are willing to add a libraries, https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus should solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `package` scheme to use `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED`. [Here's a link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/aX5-fMbdPR8) with some discussion about it.

Another alternative is to wait a bit and check to see if the deleted package is still installed by using [getPackageInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)). You'll want to wrap the call in a try/catch; if it isn't installed, it will throw a `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException`.

Comment: regularly checking for my target app helped resolve the problem in short time. Not perfect solution but for the time being works for me.